# Zero Vector space in $\Bbb R^n$ is not the zero vector in $V$

Tags: vector-spaces

Let $V= \left\{(x_1， x_2)\middle|x_1,x_2 \in\Bbb R\right\}$.

For $(x_1, x_2), (y_1,y_2) ∈ V$; and $c ∈ \Bbb R$, define
$$(x_1,x_2) + (y_1,y_2) = (x_1 + y_1 + 1,x_2 + y_2 + 1),$$
$$ c(x_1, x_2) = (cx_1, cx_2)$$

Show that $0_{\Bbb R^2} = (0,0) ≠ 0_V$, that is, show that the zero vector in $\Bbb R^2$ is not the
zero vector in $V$.

Comment: We don't know what $V$ is. Please provide more context.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  A zero vector is an element of a vector space that is the additive identity; in the vector space $\mathbb R^2$ it's $(0,0)$, whereas in the vector space $\mathbb R^3$ it's $(0,0,0)$, for example

Comment: The zero vector in whatever context you are talking about is going to be that vector who when added to any other vector doesn't change the result.  Of course, what the zero vector explicitly looks like will change depending on context (*maybe we were talking about a vector space made up of real numbers, or a vector space made up of matrices, or a vector space made up of functions, or a vector space made up of puppy names if such a thing made sense*) and so that zero vector is an element of that space (*be it a real number, or a matrix, or a function, or a puppy name*).

Comment: Whichever context it is that we are working in, we might still choose to notate it the same way... with the symbol $0$.  This is regardless whether or not it is a real number, a matrix, a function, or a puppy name, or what have you... and if you want to make it clear *which* zero vector and from what context it comes from, you can put a subscript with it, such as $0_V$.  And whichever context it came from, as mentioned, it has the nice property that if you "add" it to another vector from the same space that it doesn't change it, i.e. $0_V+v = v+0_V = v$ for all $v\in V$.

Comment: i have edited my problem more properly

Comment: There is not enough information in the question to even guess what you are asking. What is $f$, for example?

Comment: @copper.hat this is all I got from my question!

Comment: @JMoravitz how did you type the 0 subscript V?

Comment: I have no idea what $f$ is?

Comment: See the [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1868/list-of-generalizations-of-common-questions) for how to get subscripts, superscripts, and all that other good stuff.

Comment: @copper.hatco so sorry, I made mistake here!

Comment: @AlvinLepikv thx.

Comment: Now that you have added information about a specific $V$ that you are interested in, it is worth pointing out that as it is defined it is *not* a vector space because it fails the field axioms.  In particular, notice that $1\cdot (1,1) + 1\cdot (1,1)$ should have been equal to $2\cdot (1,1)$ by combining coefficients which would have simplified to $(2,2)$ according to the proposed rules for coefficients.  However... we find that $(1,1)+(1,1)=(3,3)$, so it is wrong here to call $V$ a vector space.  It is merely a set imbued with a binary operation

Answer (score 2):

$0_V$ is the element of $V$ such that for every $v\in V$, 
$$v+0_V =0_V+v=v$$
We need to check the result of $v+0_{\Bbb R^2}$ and $0_{\Bbb R^2}+v$. If one of those two sum doesn't give $v$, it is not the zero of $V$.

Let $(x_1, x_2)\in V$
$$(x_1, x_2) +(0, 0)=(x_1+0+1, x_2+0+1)=(x_1+1, x_2+1)\neq(x_1, x_2)$$
then $0_{\Bbb R^2}=(0, 0)$ is not the zero of $V$.

In fact, the zero of $V$ is $0_V=(-1, -1)$ since
$$v+0_V=(x_1, x_2)+(-1, -1)=(x_1+(-1)+1, x_2+(-1)+1)=(x_1, x_2)=v$$
$$0_V+v=(-1, -1)+(x_1, x_2)=((-1)+x_1+1, (-1)+x_2+1)=(x_1, x_2)=v$$

Comment: is V a vector space over R?@Alain Remillard

Comment: @A.H $V$ will be a vector space over whatever field you say that it is a vector space over at the time of defining the vector space in question.

Comment: @A.H The problem is with distributivity. In order to be a vector space, it should satisfy $c(v_1+v_2)=cv_1+cv_2$ for all $v_2, v_2\in V$ and for all $c\in\Bbb R$. With your addition and multiplication, it is not the case. So $V$ is not a vector space over $\Bbb R$.

Comment: @AlainRemillard Thank you so mcuh for your replying, I guess I gain more understandings about the vector space now. I do have another question, "show that the vector space holds by producing an ordered pair -v such that v+(-v)=0$_v$ " What does " an ordered pair -v" mean here???

Comment: @A.H Given a particular element $v$ which can be written as $(v_1,v_2)$ in your context, it is asking you to find the *additive inverse* of $v$, which is written as $-v$, which is that element such that when added to $v$ results in the zero vector for $V$.  That is $v+(-v) = 0_V$